# Does 声 exist as a traditional character?

Tags: etymology, traditional-characters, traditional-vs-simplified, glyph-origin

I see that 声 has an entry in the Kangxi dictionary, but every site seems to define 声 as a simplification of 聲. Does 声 also exist as a traditional character? If not, then what's the glyph origin behind 殸?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes,「声」represented the word now written as「磬」(*stone chimes*).

「声」was originally part of「殸」(*stone chimes*), and this character later became「磬」. Later on, people began cutting off the components from「聲」(*sound*) to use「声」as a shorthand for「聲」(*sound*), but「磬」and「聲」represented different words.

> 「聲」(*sound*) is comprised of「殸」(*stone chimes being struck*) and「耳」(*ear*).

---

<kbd>[商](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shang_dynasty)
[甲](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oracle_bone_script)
[image]
[前](http://xiaoxue.iis.sinica.edu.tw/yanbian/Reference/JiaguwenReference)7.42.1
[合集8613](http://www.guoxuedashi.com/jgwhj/?bhfl=1&bh=8613&jgwfl=)</kbd><kbd>[春秋](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spring_and_Autumn_period)
金
[image]
鎛</kbd>
　
<kbd>[篆](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Small_seal_script)
[image]
[說文解字](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shuowen_Jiezi)</kbd>
　<kbd>今
[楷](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_script)
[image]</kbd>

「声」depicts *stone chimes*「石」suspended with *threads/string*. In「殸」, *a hand holding a striking implement*「殳」was added to emphasise that the instrument is meant to be struck. Finally, another semantic「石」(*rock, stone*) was added on to「殸」, as a further emphasis that the instrument was made of stone.

In the modern form, the *threads* used for suspending the chimes is written as「士」.

> <kbd>商
> 甲
> [image]
> [乙](http://xiaoxue.iis.sinica.edu.tw/yanbian/Reference/JiaguwenReference)3212
> [合集13505](http://www.guoxuedashi.com/jgwhj/?bhfl=1&bh=13505&jgwfl=)</kbd><kbd>商
> 甲
> [image]
> 乙1277
> [合集376](http://www.guoxuedashi.com/jgwhj/?bhfl=1&bh=376&jgwfl=)</kbd><kbd>西周
> 金
> [image]
> 己侯貉子簋
> [集成3977](http://www.guoxuedashi.com/yzjwjc/?bh=3977&jgwfl=)</kbd><kbd>[東漢](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Han_dynasty#Eastern_Han)
> [隸](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clerical_script)
> [image]
> 景北海碑陰</kbd>
> 　<kbd>今
> 楷
> [image]</kbd>
>
> 「石」was originally a depiction of *stone chimes*, and its original meaning is *stone, rock*. A *distinguishing symbol*「口」was added later to mark the name of an ancient region called「石」, and is inherited in the modern form. The *stone chimes* component was later simplified into「厂」, then the strokes were further altered slightly into「丆」, resulting in the modern shape.

---

**References:**

- 季旭昇《說文新證》
- 黃德寬《古文字譜系疏證》
- [小學堂](http://xiaoxue.iis.sinica.edu.tw/)
- [中華語文知識庫・漢字源流](http://chinese-linguipedia.org/search_source.html)
- [國學大師](http://www.guoxuedashi.com/)

  - [郭沫若《甲骨文合集》](http://www.guoxuedashi.com/jgwhj/)
  - [中國社會科學院考古研究所《殷周金文集成》](http://www.guoxuedashi.com/yzjwjc/)

Answer (score 2):

声 is a pictograph of an old stone instrument.  The radical 殳 is a hand hitting something with a stick.  The ear 耳 below 聲, must represent the hearing of the sound from this instrument being played.  See the book: "China: Empire of Living Symbols" by Cecilia Lindqvist.  If I remember correctly it is in there.

Answer (score 0):

殸 led to 聲, but was not composed from 声; it's not like evolution to ever more complexity, sometimes a component is isolated from more complex forms. 声 has been used for a thousand years, if that is "traditional" enough.